# Rectangle Drawing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Im not sure whats the best way to do this, so I better ask you.

I need to implement a graphic like this:
[image: skala]

each field is corresponds with an other variable and should be colored accordingly.

Easiest way (not fastest):

Create every object separately in XAML and do it with binding or handlers

```
<Rectangle Name="rect0_0" Fill="White" Stroke="Black"   StrokeThickness="1"  RadiusX="1" RadiusY="10" Margin="12,250,354,12" />
```

Or similar to this:

```
void InitializeRectangle()
{
    aRectangle = new RectangleGeometry[MAX_CHANNELS];
    for (int i = 0; i < aRectangle.Length; i++)
    {
        aRectangle[i] = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(recX, recY, recWidth,recHeight ));

        GeometryGroup1.Children.Add(aRectangle[i]);
        recX += recGab;
    }
}

void PaintRectangle()
{
    myPath1.Data = GeometryGroup1;
    myPath1.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
    myPath1.StrokeThickness = 1;
    mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 204, 204, 255);
    myPath1.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
    Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas();
    myCanvas.Children.Add(myPath1);
    this.Content = myCanvas;
}
```

But I cant color them separately with this method..

How can I color each Rectangle and view it in the GUI?

Comment: Or you can use an ItemContainer derived control, with a DataTemplate that contains RectangleGeometry and bind the properties to a list of items in your ViewModel that contain the data you want to display (start, end, category, color, etc)

Comment: The correct term is [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx), and it's not necessary to derive from it. Just set its `ItemTemplate` and `ItemsPanel` properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick sample to illustrate how your goal can be achieved.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestBench.GraphicSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfTestBench="clr-namespace:WpfTestBench"
        Title="Graphic sample" Height="130" Width="570">
    <!-- Outer items control to hold rows -->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="wpfTestBench:Row">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <!-- Row identifier -->
                    <Label Content="{Binding Id}" />

                    <!-- Inner items control with rectangles -->
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Squares}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="wpfTestBench:Square">
                                <Rectangle Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"
                                           Width="30" Height="20" Margin="2, 0"
                                           Fill="{Binding Value, Converter={wpfTestBench:IntToColorConverter}}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WpfTestBench
{
    public partial class GraphicSample
    {
        public GraphicSample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new GraphicContext();
        }
    }

    public class GraphicContext
    {
        private readonly Random _random = new Random();

        public GraphicContext()
        {
            Rows = new List<Row>();

            for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
                Rows.Add(new Row(_random, i));
        }

        public IList<Row> Rows { get; set; }
    }

    public class Row
    {
        private const int Size = 16;

        public Row(Random random, int id)
        {
            Id = id;
            Squares = new List<Square>();

            for (var i = 0; i < Size; i++)
                Squares.Add(new Square(random.Next(20)));
        }

        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public IList<Square> Squares { get; private set; }
    }

    public class Square
    {
        public Square(int value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Converter:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfTestBench
{
    public class IntToColorConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        private static IntToColorConverter _instance;

        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var convertedValue = (int)value;

            if (convertedValue < 5)
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

            if (convertedValue < 10)
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);

            if (convertedValue < 15)
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);

            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }

        #endregion

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return _instance ?? (_instance = new IntToColorConverter());
        }
    }
}
```

Execution result:

[image: Sample result]

Comment: thanks so much for that piece of code. You did in a hundred lines what I accomblished in 1500+, and thats only for 16 squares :D

Comment: You are welcome! ItemsControl and its descendants are the very powerful tools once you know how to use them.